# TableView changes not work correctly in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

I'm using a `UITableView` in **SwiftUI**. I get data from WebSocket and I want to update my tableview live. I successfully get the data from the network and update it in viewModel and pass it to `QuotesTableView`.

TableView does not update my data correctly, i.e tableViewData's first value is Symbol1 but it shows Symbol1 data in first `IndexPath`. I debug it in `cellForRowAt` function and see I get correct data, but does not show the correct item in cell. It randomly changes the order of the data in my tableview but tableviewData's order does not change.

```
   @StateObject private var viewModel = QuotesViewModel()

   var body: some View {
      ZStack {
         Color.init(hex: "#293c54").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

         QuotesTableView(tableViewData: $viewModel.list)
            .background(Color.clear)
      }
   }
```

```
import Combine

class QuotesViewModel: ObservableObject {
   var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
   
   // MARK: - Input
   var selectedSymbols: String
   
   /// Symbols list
   @Published var list: [SymbolsInDataModel] = .init()
   
   // MARK: - Output
   
   // MARK: - Init
   init() {
      
      socket = SocketManager.shared
      
      observeSocketValues()
      bindView()
   }
   
   // MARK: - Business Logic
   let socket: SocketManager
   
   // MARK: - Config
}

// MARK: - Bind View
extension QuotesViewModel {
   /// observe view actions in here...
   func bindView() {
      
   }
}


// MARK: - Observation Socket Data
extension QuotesViewModel {
   func observeSocketValues() {
      socket.$symbolsList.sink(receiveValue: { newSymbols in
         self.list = newSymbols
      })
      .store(in: &cancellables)

      
      socket.$symbolsList
         .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
         .first { _ in
            self.list = self.socket.symbolsList
            return true
         }
         .sink(receiveValue: {_ in})
         .store(in: &cancellables)
   }
}
```

```
struct QuotesTableView: UIViewRepresentable {   
   // The data source for the table view
   @Binding var tableViewData: [SymbolsInDataModel]
   var selectClicked: ((_ item: SymbolsInDataModel) -> Void)?
   
   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
      let tableView = UITableView()
      tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
      tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
      tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
      tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
      tableView.register(HostingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
      
      return tableView
   }
   
   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
      // Reload the table view data whenever the data changes
      
      uiView.reloadData()

   }
   
   func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
      Coordinator(self)
   }
 
}



// MARK: - CompetitionsTableView -> Coordinator
extension QuotesTableView {
   class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
      
      var parent: QuotesTableView
      
      init(_ tableView: QuotesTableView) {
         parent = tableView
      }
      
      func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
      }
      
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         parent.tableViewData.count
      }
      
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
      }
      
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HostingCell
         tableViewCell.backgroundColor = .clear
         
         print("indexpath: \(indexPath.row) item: \(parent.tableViewData[indexPath.row])")
         
         // Set the root view of the hosting controller to the view for this cell
         let row = parent.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
         let hostingController = UIHostingController(
            rootView: AnyView(
               QuotesCellView(item: row, selectAction: self.parent.selectClicked)
            )
         )
         
         hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
         
         // create & setup hosting controller only once
         if tableViewCell.host == nil {
            tableViewCell.host = hostingController
            
            let tableCellViewContent = hostingController.view!
            tableCellViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            tableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(tableCellViewContent)
            tableCellViewContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
         } else {
            // reused cell, so just set other SwiftUI root view
            tableViewCell.host = hostingController
         }
         tableViewCell.setNeedsLayout()
         return tableViewCell
         
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: When a table view cell is reused you are assigning a new hostingController but the view is not changed. So it will show the data from the last time this cell was used for a different row.

Comment: how can I fix it? can you show me a code example, please?

Comment: `Coordinator(self)` is a bug, if `QuotesTableView` is re-init then `self` is an old value, `makeCoordinator` is only called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem with recycling cells you either need to change the data in the hosting view or create a new one. Your old code seems to want to make a new one (which is less efficient) so a small change to remove the old hosting view should fix that issue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HostingCell
         tableViewCell.backgroundColor = .clear
         
         print("indexpath: \(indexPath.row) item: \(parent.tableViewData[indexPath.row])")
         
         // Set the root view of the hosting controller to the view for this cell
         let row = parent.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
         let hostingController = UIHostingController(
            rootView: AnyView(
               QuotesCellView(item: row, selectAction: self.parent.selectClicked)
            )
         )
         
         hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear

         // remove any previous view if the cell is being reused
         tableViewCell.host?.view.removeFromSuperView()
         
         // create & setup hosting controller
         tableViewCell.host = hostingController
            
         let tableCellViewContent = hostingController.view!
         tableCellViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         tableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(tableCellViewContent)
         tableCellViewContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
         tableCellViewContent.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
         tableCellViewContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
         tableCellViewContent.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
       
         tableViewCell.setNeedsLayout()
         return tableViewCell
         
      }
```